# Is there a keyboard shortcut to paste in password in Linux?

Tags: automatic-logon

With my laptop going to sleep when unused for just a few minutes, it is necessary to type in my password each time.

A shortcut key would be wonderful, is this possible somehow?

Comment: A shortcut key would make the password useless, so you could as well disable the password prompt then?

Comment: I have to agree with Jan. What is the point of a password if you're gonna keep it in the clipboard the whole time anyway? Have the computer not ask for a password when it goes to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/), but in general, this is not a good idea.

If you're using a GNOME based distro, such as Ubuntu, if I recall correctly, you can go into the Screensaver settings (System > Preferences > Screensaver (?), and uncheck "Lock screen when screensaver is active" and you won't need to use your password when you "Wake up" your computer.